# The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am using entity framework database. But when I run my application, I got an exception named "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code. The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context".

I got errror in `context.Users.Add(df);` part which is in `LoginController`.

My entity database code is as shown below:
Model:User.cs

```cs
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MVCRegistrationAndLogin.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string abc { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCRegistrationAndLogin.Models;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace MVCRegistrationAndLogin.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var db = new MyDbModelEntities())
            {
                return View(db.Users.ToList());
            }
        }

        public ActionResult UserLogin()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            using (MyDbModelEntities context = new MyDbModelEntities())
            {
                var user = from u in context.Users
                           where u.UserName == username
                           select u;

                if (user.ToList().Count == 1)
                {
                    if (user.First().Password == CreatePasswordHash(password, user.First().abc))
                    {
                        Session["logged"] = user.First().UserName;
                        return RedirectToAction("ShowProducts", "Products");
                    }
                }
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("_loginError", "Error in username and password");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();

            return RedirectToAction("UserLogin", "Login");
        }

        private static string CreateSalt()
        {
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] byteArr = new byte[64];
            rng.GetBytes(byteArr);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArr);
        }

        private static string CreatePasswordHash(string password, string aa)
        {
            string passwrodSalt = String.Concat(password, aa);
            string hashedPwd = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(passwrodSalt, "sha1");
            return hashedPwd;
        }

        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(User df)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new MyDbModelEntities())
                {
                    df.abc = CreateSalt();
                    df.Password = CreatePasswordHash(df.Password, df.abc);
                    **context.Users.Add(df);**
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                var outputLines = new List<string>();
                foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    outputLines.Add(string.Format(
                        "{0}: Entity of type \"{1}\" in state \"{2}\" has the following validation errors:",
                        DateTime.Now, eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State));
                    foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        outputLines.Add(string.Format(
                            "- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                            ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage));
                    }
                }
                //Write to file
                System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(@"c:\temp\tulsi_errors.txt", outputLines);

                // Showing it on screen
                throw new Exception(string.Join(",", outputLines.ToArray()));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

view:

Register.cshtml

```html
@model MVCRegistrationAndLogin.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>Register</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>


    <div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

UserLogin.cshtml

```html
@model MVCRegistrationAndLogin.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserLogin";
}

<h2>UserLogin</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed due to wrong credentials!!!")
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>


    <div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("New Registration", "Register")
    </div>
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Need more information, such as which controller method was executing when the error occurred.  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Register Method is executing when error occurred. When Register method is trying to store the password into the database named user,at that time this error occurred. the errored line of code is:  context.Users.Add(df);

Comment: You're pouring out a bucket of code. But asking a good question is about showing *relevant* code. `User` is relevant and the part of the action method throwing the error. The rest is surplus. About the error: apparently the context `MyDbModelEntities` doesn't know about `User`. Have you got multiple types of contexts?